# Android Broadcast Receiver terminates automatically without performing whole task

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

i want to get the location co-ordinates after boot up using Broadcast Receiver. But my code not working many times(works very few times only).The application not waiting until Location manager get coordinates.please help me. thanks in advance.  This is my code

```
`LocationManager lm=(LocationManager)context.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        Toast.makeText(context,"location listner",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        LocationListener ll=new LocationListener() {
            @Override

            public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

                if(co<=0) {
                    double la=location.getLatitude();
                    double lo=location.getLongitude();
                    try {
                        SmsManager sms=SmsManager.getDefault();
                        Toast.makeText(context,"lat "+lo+" lon "+la,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        co++;
                        sms.sendTextMessage(number,null,"Langitude "+la+" lattitude "+lo ,null,null);

                    } catch (Exception ex) {
                        ex.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
                Location location=new Location(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);


            }

            @Override
            public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {


            }
        };
        lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,100,0,ll);

    Toast.makeText(context,"went out .....",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

}`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `BroadcastReceiver` only has a lifetime as long as its `onReceive` method is executing. After that method returns, it is no longer present and the `Context` object provided to it is no longer valid. So registering an asynchronous callback like a `LocationListener` will not work reliably. I'm actually surprised it ever works.

Instead, use your `BroadcastReceiver` to start a `Service` and have the `Service` register a listener with the `LocationManager`. The `Service` will stay until either explicitly stopped or the system kills it because of memory pressure.

Comment: nice suggestion bro, but the LocationListener working fine with **ON_RECEIVE_SMS**  broadcast receiver. the onReceive method waits until the LocationListener get the coordinates. But not in case of **RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETE**, why?

Comment: It happens to work for you, on occasion, according to your question. I'm telling you why. Broadcast receivers have a very limited lifetime. As for `ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED`, your app must have an activity which is strted by the user before the app is allowed to receive that broadcast. It's a security feature to avoid apps running in the background after install but before the user has ever started them.